# App store now accept application which using deployment target 6.0

Tags: ios

I have developed an application in iOS 6 platform with deployment target 6.0. Can i submit my application to app store without build against iOS7?

Comment: Before submitting the app u have to test it on IOS 7 device. hence they will test on latest OS only..

Comment: Yes you can. But you should handle errors that might occur if your app is running on iOS7 device, and you'll probably have some Apple warnings if some app icons are missing (like the new 120x120)